# range when doing operations on signed and unsigned integers

Tags: c

I have noticed something weird and I would really appreciate if someone could help me to understand what's happening on a deeper level.

```
temp1 = 0x3a
temp2 = 0xfb

printf("%x", abs(temp1 - temp2))
```

will print `0x3f` if temp1, temp2 were of type `int8_t`.

will print `0xc1` if temp1, temp2 were of type `int16_t`.

will print `0xc1` if temp1, temp2 were of type `uint8_t`.

now I understand that int16_8 and uint8_t has bigger positive range, but I still don't understand what's going on, I tried int8_t and to use casting

`printf("%x", abs((int16_t) (temp1) - (int16_t)(temp2)))`

The program printed `0x3f` (I expected to get `0xc1`) which is really confusing

Comment: Don't forget that none of the arithmetic is done using types `int8_t` or `uint8_t`, and it is unlikely that any of the arithmetic is done using `int16_t` — it is all done using type `int`.  You'd only get arithmetic in `int16_t` if the type `int` is the same as `int16_t`, which is unlikely unless you're using some sort of embedded CPU.

Comment: I completely forgot about that, but it still doesn't explain why am I getting this results

Comment: It probably does account for the trouble, but I've not sat down and worked out what's going on. Assigning `0xF8` to an `int8_t` is nominally a bit dubious; the `int` constant is too large to fit in a signed 8-bit integer. In practice, it'll probably work and it'll probably work as expected. You should have a version of your code that carefully prints all the inputs and intermediate results as well as the result.  Remember that `abs()` returns an `int` too. It will probably have multiple functions, one for each of the types `int8_t`, `int16_t` and `uint8_t` that you use for `temp1` and `temp2`.

Comment: To understand what's happening under the hood, are you familiar with the concept of sign extension?

Comment: In short, on a typical two's-complement implementation, the signedness of the type doesn't affect the bit pattern used to represent a value, but it does affect the algorithm used to convert one type to another.  Signed types are promoted by sign extension, unsigned types by zero extension.  And that is how the difference in results arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `temp1` and `temp2` have type `int8_t`, then `temp1 = 0x3a` sets `temp1` to 58 (the value of `0x3a`), but it is implementation-defined what `temp2 = 0xfb` sets `temp2` to, because the value of `0xfb` (251) is too large for `int8_t`. Commonly, a C implementation will set it to −5 (which equals 251−256 and which has the same bit encoding in two’s complement as 251 does in unsigned binary).

Then `temp1 - temp2` is 58 − −5 = 63, for which the absolute value is 63, the value of `0x3f`.

If `temp1` and `temp2` have type `int16_t` or `uint8_t`, then `temp1 = 0x3a` sets `temp1` to 58, as before, and `temp2 = 0xfb` sets `temp2` to 251.

Then `temp1 - temp2` is 58 − 251 = −193, for which the absolute value is 193, the value of `0xc1`. Note that, in the evaluation of `temp1 - temp2`, values of type `int16_t` or `uint8_t` are automatically promoted to `int`, so the arithmetic is done using the `int` type and produces −193 even if the types of `temp1` and `temp2` are `uint8_t`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but doesn't the binary representation stays the same? so when using int16_t or uint8_t or int8_t, 0xfb will always translate to 0b11111010, so what difference does it make in terms of arithmetic of the cpu? 
Edit: Added more information to the comment

Comment: @Waad: The binary representation of what? The value put into `temp2` when the right side of the `=` is out of range? That is up to the C implementation. C 2018 6.3.1.3 3 says either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. It is common that compiler implementors choose to define this to wrap modulo 2^8 for 8-bit types, which preserves the bit pattern when two’s complement is in use.